# How to write equation as shown in picture using Latex?

Tags: equations

[image]

how we write this equation in latex in given form

Comment: Nice try, but even the most comprehensive answer won't help you much. You won't get written all of your equations here. Learn LaTeX. Read an introduction and the command `texdoc packagename`is a great help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It looks like there's already a few solutions posted below. Great. However may I suggest that next time you ask a question, mention what you have already tried. 

e.g. Have you figured out how to write a gamma on its own? Have you figured out how to write a fraction? How to write du/dz? etc. The more effort you demonstrate you have put in, the more effort others will be willing to put in for you. It also helps us understand *precisely* which part of the task you need help with.

Comment: I have downvoted, because this question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Here is the solution given by the powerful [Mathpix Snipping Tool](https://mathpix.com/) `$u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+w \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\lambda_{1}\left(\begin{array}{c}u^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+v^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}+w^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial z^{2}} \\ +2 u v \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+2 v w \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y \partial z}+2 u w \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial \tilde{z}}\end{array}\right)=\nu \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial z^{2}}$`.

Answer (score 28):

With a few shortcut macros it's much easier:

plain TeX version:

```
\let~\catcode~`86~`j0~`X13~`C1~`D2~`M3jdefX81C~`8113jdefDXZZ81C~
`8113DXYY81CZ81jletDYLLjletYFFjfiYNNjdefYPPjpartialZIZAZBZj{Zj}Y
EEjexpandafterYOOjelseYKKjifxNI818283CL}81NAC82DNBC83Djfuturelet
jTjHDNjHCKjT}L{AOL{BF{DXUUCI)jpCjp)CDDDY VVjoverNjp)818283CKX81X
CP82VP83DOCP^C81D82VjbC81DC83DDFDYRRjrelaxNjb8182Cjd8182RDNjd81%
8283CK83RP82^C81DOP82P83FDY!!uY@@vY##wY$$xYj%%yY&&zXvv81C81^2DMM
!U!$+@U!%+#U!&+jlambda_1jleft(v!U)2! $+v@U)2!%+v#U)2!&jatop+2!@U
)2!C$%D+2@#U)2!C%&D+2!#U)2!C$&Djright)=jnuU)2!&jeqno(1.25)MMjbye
```

LaTeX version:

```
\documentclass{article}\begin{document}
\let~\catcode~`86~`j0~`X13~`C1~`D2~`M3jdefX81C~`8113jdefDXZZ81C~
`8113DXYY81CZ81jletDYLLjletYFFjfiYNNjdefYPPjpartialZIZAZBZj{Zj}Y
EEjexpandafterYOOjelseYKKjifxNI818283CL}81NAC82DNBC83Djfuturelet
jTjHDNjHCKjT}L{AOL{BF{DXUUCI)jpCjp)CDDDY VVjoverNjp)818283CKX81X
CP82VP83DOCP^C81D82VjbC81DC83DDFDYRRjrelaxNjb8182Cjd8182RDNjd81%
8283CK83RP82^C81DOP82P83FDY!!uY@@vY##wY$$xYj%%yY&&zXvv81C81^2DMM
!U!$+@U!%+#U!&+jlambda_1jleft(v!U)2!$+v@U)2!%+v#U)2!&jatop+2!@U)
2!C$%D+2@#U)2!C%&D+2!#U)2!C$&Djright)=jnuU)2!&jeqno(1.25)MMjstop
```

output:

> [image]

---

Inspired by David Carlisle's [`xii`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xii?lang=en) :)

Comment: +1 for snarkiness.

Comment: I don't think MiKTeX gave me a TeX engine.

Comment: @ahorn Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You didn't find the `tex` executable?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I just don't know how to run TeX code, so I thought I'd leave a comment. Sorry for the clutter.

Comment: @ahorn No worries, we can delete them later :-) Do you run LaTeX from the command line or from an IDE? If the latter, then which one? TeXMaker? TeXStudio? Another?

Comment: I prefer TeXWorks.  Sometimes through MiKTeX on Windows, but my main computer uses the TeXWorks package on Linux.

Comment: @ahorn TeXWorks already has options for `pdftex`, `xetex`, and `luatex`, which all run plain TeX, and the test file above will work on any of them. But if you want Knuth's TeX engine, then here's what you'll do. Open TeXWorks then click the `Edit` menu Item and `Preferences`, then on the window that pops up go to the `Typesetting` tab. In this window there is a list `Provessing tools` and in the lower right side of this list there is a `+` button; click on it and a `Tool Configuration` window should open. Continued...

Comment: @ahorn ...continuation: Configure it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqAYO.png then click OK. Now click the `+` again and configure the new window like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icu2V.png and click OK again and once more. Now in the main windows of TeXWorks, in the list of typesetting tools to the right of the “play” button, you should have a `TeX` tool and a `DVI -> PDF` tool. Knuth's TeX produces only DVI output so you can run a file with TeX and then run `DVI -> PDF` to convert it to PDF. Tell me if it worked :-)

Comment: Thanks. This is good enough to be a Q&A.

Comment: @ahorn Indeed, it's always best to ask a question. Feel free to do so ;-)

Answer (score 6):

A variation on the theme, but with a greater emphasis on simplifying the input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\pdiff}{\mathop{}\!\partial}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pder}{omm}
 {
  \frac{\pdiff\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}#2}{\faisal_pder_vars:n { #3 }}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \faisal_pder_vars:n
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \pdiff##1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
u\pder{u}{x}+v\pder{u}{y}+w\pder{u}{z}+
  \lambda_1
  \left(\begin{gathered}
    u^2\pder[2]{u}{x^2}+v\pder[2]{u}{y^2}+w^2\pder[2]{u}{z^2}\\
    \mspace{-\medmuskip}{}
    +2uv\pder[2]{u}{x,y}+2vw\pder[2]{u}{y,z}+2uw\pder[2]{u}{x,z}
    \end{gathered}\right)
= \nu\pder[2]{u}{z^2},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u\pder{u}{x}&+v\pder{u}{y}+w\pder{u}{z}
+\lambda_1\biggl(
    u^2\pder[2]{u}{x^2}+v\pder[2]{u}{y^2}+w^2\pder[2]{u}{z^2}
\\
&+2uv\pder[2]{u}{x,y}+2vw\pder[2]{u}{y,z}+2uw\pder[2]{u}{x,z}\biggr)
= \nu\pder[2]{u}{z^2},
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The syntax for `\pder` is

1. optional argument for the order of the derivative (if greater than 1)
2. function to differentiate
3. list of the variables the derivative is taken with respect to, comma separated

In the first case I used `\mspace{-\medmuskip}{}+` in order to have the plus sign correctly spaced. I used `gathered` instead of `pmatrix` because it is semantically sounder.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    $u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+w\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}
    u^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+v\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+w^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\\+2uv\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+2vw\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y\partial z}+2uw\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial z}
    \end{pmatrix} = v\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2},$
\end{document}
```

this will give you:

[image]

PS: Welcome to TeX.se, from next time, please provide a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+...
    +\lambda_1 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    u^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+...\\
    + 2 uv \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}+...
    \end{pmatrix} = v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your code and replace `...` by `\dots` (or `\cdots` when not between two plus signs).

Comment: @Sigur I have added the three  dots to indicate to OP that he has to complete the equation by himself. The final version of the equation should not have  dots within it.

Answer (score 2):

Borrow a little from all answer and make a little change (such as change `v` to `\nu` in the right-hand side)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+w\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}
    u^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+v\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+w^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\\+2uv\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+2vw\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y\partial z}+2uw\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial z}
    \end{pmatrix} = \nu\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2},
    \tag{1.25}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \[ u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+ w \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \lambda_1 
  \left( \begin{tabular}{c}
 $\:\:\:\:\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}$\\ 
 $+ 2 u v \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}+ 2vw  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y\partial z}+2wu  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z \partial u}$\\\end{tabular} \right) = \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\] 
\end{document}
```

This gives desired output.

Answer (score -1):

```
$$u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+w \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\lambda_{1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
u^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+v^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}+w^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial z^{2}} \\
+2 u v \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}+2 v w \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \partial \partial z}+2 u w \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial z}
\end{array}\right)=\nu \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial z^{2}}$$
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I didn't downvote for your answer. Please, expand your answer by giving fully compilable code starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`