# How to call a command accepting 2 optional args defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` and pass only 2nd optional arg to it (skipping the 1st)?

Tags: macros, xparse

If `\myB` accepts two optional arguments, `\myB` sets both of them to default values, `\myB[5]` sets first to `5` and second to default value, `\myB[5][10]` sets first to `5` and second to `10`. But how do we set `#2` argument only? Doing `\myB[][10]` does NOT set first argument to default value (it just makes it disappear).

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
% each of two optional arguments defaults to zero
\NewDocumentCommand{\myB}{O{0}O{0}}
  {%
    myB: #1, #2%
  }
\begin{document}
% how to call `myB` so that it only has #2 set? (not #1)
\myB[][6] % this is no good since `[]` removes default zero
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the general issue with two optional arguments back-to-back: if they are no co-dependent, giving the second alone is always an issue.

Comment: @bp2017 You could check if the first argument is empty: `\tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{myB:~0,~#2}{myB:~#1,~#2}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, why do you need `~` before args?

Comment: @bp2017 you don't need it here, but if you turn `\ExplSyntaxOn` a normal space is ignored and `~` will be a normal space instead. I guess he wrote that out of habit (or to be more precise, you'll need `\ExplSyntaxOn` to use `\tl_if_empty:nTF`).

Comment: @Skillmon I thought of that. But `\IfNoValueTF` checks only for `-NoValue-`. It won't work for `[][6]` because `#1` will be empty.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You're right, my bad. We could do something like `O{0} s O{0}` and then you can use `\foo*[5]` to only set the second one.

Comment: @Skillmon In that case `\IfNoValue` would work :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik but wouldn't make sense if the defaults are to be set anyway.

Comment: If one doesn't care too much about conventions of argument types, one could use `D(){0} O{0}`, too. Then `\foo(5)` would only set the first argument, `\foo[5]` the second, and `\foo(5)[5]` both.

Comment: @bp2017 normally you could use processors, but because of reasons not understandable to myself, the `-NoValue-` flag wouldn't ever be passed to an argument processor.

Comment: I think the best solution is to include an optional single token between the two arguments which you don't really need. This way you get the full versatility without introducing too questionable syntax.

Comment: @bp2017 if you want to introduce a key=value syntax you can take a look at the `l3keys`module (or any other key-value package), but the `#2=foo` syntax doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: @Skillmon Did you ask for _questionable syntax_?! Define `\NewDocumentCommand{\myB}{E{12}{{0}{0}}}{myB: #1, #2}` and use `\myB2{6}`. Problem. Solved. :D

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik we don't do that here :)

Comment: @bp2017 `\NewDocumentCommand \foo { O{0} } { myB:~#1,~\baz } \NewDocumentCommand \baz { O{0} } { #1 }`?! Or do you mean that you need to pass optional arguments on to another macro like `\NewDocumentCommand \foo { o o } { \IfNoValueTF { #2 } { \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { \baz } { \baz [ { #1 } ] } } { \baz [ { #1 } ] [ { #2 } ] } }`

Comment: @bp2017 if you meant the latter, I might do this with argument processors as well: `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bdmmxvii_Oarg_pass_proc:n #1 { \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 } { \cs_set:Npn \ProcessedArgument {} } { \cs_set:Npn \ProcessedArgument { [ { #1 } ] } } } \NewDocumentCommand \foo { >{ \__bdmmxvii_Oarg_pass_proc:n } O{} O{0} } { \baz #1 { #2 } }` if the first argument of `\baz` is optional and the second mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Phelype Oleinik suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490508/how-to-call-a-command-accepting-2-optional-args-defined-with-newdocumentcomman#comment1238578_490508) you could use an empty first optional argument and assign the default if it is empty. I'd do that with an argument processor:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bdmmxvii_Oarg_proc:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
      { \cs_set:Npn \ProcessedArgument { #1 } }
      { \cs_set:Npn \ProcessedArgument { #2 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \twooptsA { >{ \__bdmmxvii_Oarg_proc:nn { 0 } }O{} O{0} }
  {
    myB:~#1,~#2
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Alternatively my suggestion with the star:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \twooptsB { O{0} s O{0} }
  {
    myB:~#1,~#3
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

And as a third option a key=value syntax:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { bdmmxvii }
  {
    ,1 .tl_set:N  = \__bdmmxvii_arg_a_tl
    ,1 .initial:n = 0
    ,2 .tl_set:N  = \__bdmmxvii_arg_b_tl
    ,2 .initial:n = 0
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \twooptsC { O{} }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { bdmmxvii } { #1 }
    \__bdmmxvii_twooptsC:VV \__bdmmxvii_arg_a_tl \__bdmmxvii_arg_b_tl
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__bdmmxvii_twooptsC:nn #1 #2
  {
    myB:~#1,~#2
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__bdmmxvii_twooptsC:nn { VV }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Everything together in a single document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bdmmxvii_Oarg_proc:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
      { \cs_set:Npn \ProcessedArgument { #1 } }
      { \cs_set:Npn \ProcessedArgument { #2 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \twooptsA { >{ \__bdmmxvii_Oarg_proc:nn { 0 } }O{} O{0} }
  {
    myB:~#1,~#2
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \twooptsB { O{0} s O{0} }
  {
    myB:~#1,~#3
  }
\keys_define:nn { bdmmxvii }
  {
    ,1 .tl_set:N  = \__bdmmxvii_arg_a_tl
    ,1 .initial:n = 0
    ,2 .tl_set:N  = \__bdmmxvii_arg_b_tl
    ,2 .initial:n = 0
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \twooptsC { O{} }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { bdmmxvii } { #1 }
    \__bdmmxvii_twooptsC:VV \__bdmmxvii_arg_a_tl \__bdmmxvii_arg_b_tl
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__bdmmxvii_twooptsC:nn #1 #2
  {
    myB:~#1,~#2
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__bdmmxvii_twooptsC:nn { VV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\twooptsA\ \twooptsA[1][2] \twooptsA[1] \twooptsA[][2]

\twooptsB\ \twooptsB[1][2] \twooptsB[1] \twooptsB*[2]

\twooptsC\ \twooptsC[1=1,2=2] \twooptsC[1=1] \twooptsC[2=2]
\end{document}
```

Everything results in the same:

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `E` argument :(

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you might go for it, I don't like `E` types very much (but they are so powerful, why is it considered questionable syntax?) and they still are experimental.

Comment: Just kidding ;) The `E` type, even though experimental, seems very robust, and is not considered questionable. How one use it, on the other hand...

Comment: Why did you use `\ExplSyntaxOn` in star syntax?

Comment: @bp2017 I used `\ExplSyntaxOn` on all of them because they all were in that regime in my full document. Also the meaning of `~` would change and you'd have to make sure not to introduce parasitic spaces.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that is not questionable syntax (the usage of it, not the implementation in `xparse`)? If so behold my new answers from now on, spoiling `E` and `e` everywhere :)

Comment: @Skillmon No syntax is questionable syntax if properly used. ([good syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484417/134574)--[not-so good syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490508#comment1238600_490508)--[best syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474872/134574)).

Answer (score 2):

This is bad syntax and you should consider to avoid it.

Anyway, you can preprocess the argument. Of course, you cannot set the first optional argument to empty.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfEmpty}{mm}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
   { \tl_set:Nn \ProcessedArgument { #1 } }
   { \tl_set:Nn \ProcessedArgument { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\myB}{>{\IfEmpty{0}}O{0}O{0}}{%
  \#1 is #1 -- \#2 is #2
}

\begin{document}

\myB

\myB[1]

\myB[1][2]

\myB[][3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it a bad syntax?

Comment: @bp2017 Because you are specifying the first optional argument when you don't want to set a value for it.

Comment: This is (almost) exactly the same as my first code block in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: use different argument delimiters, with the specifier `D`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myB}{ D(){0} O{0} }{%
  \#1 = #1, \#2 = #2%
}

\myB       % #1 = 0, #2 = 0
\myB(1)    % #1 = 1, #2 = 0
\myB[2]    % #1 = 0, #2 = 2
\myB(1)[2] % #1 = 1, #2 = 2
```